# How do I link a library file in GCC that does not start with lib?

Tags: linker, gnu-toolchain

When I link a library such as libm in with ld, I need to drop the lib prefix. What if the file does not follow this naming convention? Is there a way to link it other than renaming the file?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can link against any library, e.g. `foo.a`, by specifying full path to it on the link line:

```
gcc main.o /path/to/foo.a
```

What you lose with non-standard library name is the ability for the linker to search for it, e.g. this will not work:

```
gcc main.o -L/path/to foo.a
```

You can avoid that lack of search by using `-l:foo.a` syntax:

```
gcc main.o -L/path/one -L/path/two -l:foo.a
```

> When I link a library such as libm in with ld

Note that in general you should *not* link anything with `ld`. Use the compiler driver instead -- it adds objects and libraries to the link line that are required for correct result.

Answer (score 25):

You *can* have the linker search for a library named without the lib prefix:

```
gcc main.o -L/path/to/foo -l:foo.a
```

This is especially useful in environments where a list of libraries is specified and the -l flag is prepended later (eg some makefiles or eclipse CDT)

Comment: Aah I see now, I didn't catch the **"-l"** in there.