# Attempting to compile with my own static C library

Tags: c, gcc, static-libraries, unix-ar, .a

I compiled a static library. I have two files.

- `mylib_1.c` with function `foo1` in it
- `mylib_2.c` with function `foo2` in it.

Both `#include "mylib.h"`.

I compiled a library like so:

```
gcc -c mylib_1.c -o mylib_1.o
gcc -c mylib_2.c -o mylib_2.o
ar cr mylib.a mylib_1.o mylib_2.o
```

Then I tried to compile `mylib_test.c` with my library.

```
#include "mylib.h"

int main(void)
{
    foo1("do something cool");
    foo2("do something cool");

    return 0;
}
```

If I compile like `gcc mylib_test.c mylib.a`, GCC succeeds and everything works fine.

If I compile like `gcc mylib_test.c -Lmylib.a`, GCC fails with:

```
C:\path\to\mylib_test.c:x: undefined reference to foo1
C:\path\to\mylib_test.c:x: undefined reference to foo2
```

Why does GCC fail?

If it makes a difference, I'm running the latest version of MinGW on Windows 7.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want the `-l` flag instead of the `-L` flag for gcc. `-L` adds library paths, whereas `-l` links to the library.

Also, if you are making that static library for Linux, its name should begin with `lib` (but [does not have to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10259822/2252948), thanks to @davmac for mentioning). So your library's file name should be `libmyLib.a`, and then you should link against it with `-lmyLib`. (Yes, I find that awkward too.).

I don't know about Windows, but I guess the Windows static library's equivalent is simply `myLib.lib`. Please verify this statement first if you are making a Windows library.

See more [here](http://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-l.htm).

Comment: "its name must begin with lib" - [not necessarily!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234208/how-do-i-link-a-library-file-in-gcc-that-does-not-start-with-lib) :)

Comment: @davmac Excellent! I'll wake up tomorrow less unintelligent.

Comment: Thanks. Had to move the `.a` into `MinGW\lib`, but otherwise, this was the answer.

Comment: @Lͬͬ̓̈́ͧͣ̽Oͭ̇͂͋̊̆͑ͧ͆͆ͫͬLͣͩ͗̾͐̚ to avoid needing to move your archive you likely need to specify _both_ the library path and the library to link against: `-L. -l:mylib.a`

Comment: Great link, btw!